# Sticky review instructions covers half of my 1366x768 screen

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

Working with reviews is now unbearable as the sticky review instructions covers entire code editor. You actually can't see the code editor on the screenshot below as it is behind the sticky review instructions.

Imvho it only makes sense to make any element sticky if the screen is not at least 1080px high. I don't mind pressing CTRL+PAGE UP to go up, sticky elements are really annoying.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking the (less) button? (definitely agree with this though after I spent 4 years in a 1366x768 when)